# React component like this

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-component

I'm looking for a React component that:

### [image]

Features needed:

- Auto scroll
- Auto transparency effect on top and bottom

Do you know some?

Thank you

Comment: Try reactstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There are some.

For example:

https://github.com/adcentury/react-mobile-picker

Demo: http://adcentury.github.io/react-mobile-picker/

2) Another way would be to find a vertical carousel and redesign it to look like your list. For example:
https://xiaody.github.io/react-touch-carousel/docs/vertical.html